# One Database Many Interfaces

Tags: mysql, database, multithreading

I have developed an interface to talk to the database. While working on the development of the interface, I didn't consider multithreading  as I thought only one user is going to be using the application but, now they want many users to work at the same time using the same interface.

So, I have one local database and 3 instances of the same application to interact with the database at the same time.

So, is the database going to handle multithreading by itself or should I add some code to handle it?

Note that it is a stand alone application and the database will be deployed on a local server.

I think I will have to create 3 users on the database server to allow them to log in right?

You could suggest any better solution from your experiences.

Comment: You can't really manage multithreading effectively across processes - at least, not in a platform-agnostic way. Databases will definitely have rush conditions but usually operations to databases can be assumed to be atomic. Just make sure caching is a minimum if you need to make sure your data is current at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create 3 users: using the same one in each instance of the application is enough.

You might not need to adapt your code to the multithreading: it depends on your application. For example, if it only reads from the db, then you don't have anything to adapt at all.
On the other hand, if you're likely to have concurrent writes, then you might need to introduce e.g. transaction. Without more details about what your application does, we can't be more specific.

For example if an instance reads a records while another updates it, the 1st one may be doing its computations with an outdated version of the record. If it's an issue, then your application should take it into account (eg: using a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html), or maybe a more higher level application logic)

Comment: The application is going to be creating records, removing records, and fetching records.

So, you mean i just add the multithreading code only where the code is going to interact with the database right?